# MySQL Optimization for query on big table with dates

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have a big MySQL table (> 26M records) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ean` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ean` (`ean`),
  KEY `quantity` (`quantity`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `reference` (`reference`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26404034 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I have to know the number of products that are out of stock day after day between 2 dates.
Here is my request:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ean`), DATE(created_at) as the_date
FROM `products`
WHERE `quantity` <= 0
AND `created_at` >= '2021-11-06 00:00:00'
AND `created_at` <= '2022-01-04 23:59:59'
GROUP BY the_date;
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN` result:

```
id select_type table partitions type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
1 SIMPLE products NULL ALL quantity,created_at NULL NULL NULL 10719596 25.00 Using where; Using filesort
```

It takes about 22 seconds. I have indexes and tried many possibility, this one is the quickest I found. Maybe it's not possible to do better with my hardware, but maybe there is another way to optimize it?

mysql  Ver 8.0.22 for FreeBSD11.4 on amd64

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply write `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ean), ...`, to make code clearer.

Comment: You're right, it's edited.

Comment: Can two products really have the same EAN code? I'd expect that column to be unique. And if it is, you don't need to do count(_distinct_ ean).

Comment: Show us the explain output.

Comment: EAN code isn't unique :( I've just added the EXPLAIN output to my post.

Answer (score 1):

What does `ean` represent?  Perhaps the "product"?  And there would be one row per product per day?

If so, get rid of `id` and add

```
PRIMARY KEY(ean, created_at)
```

(And get rid of `INDEX(ean)`.)

Then calculate the out-of-stock eans for 0each day (*for that day*) and put it in summary table.

Then do the query from the summary table, which, by the way, would have `PRIMARY KEY(created_at)`.

Comment: `ean`isn't unique so it isn't possible, but you helped me with your idea of calculate for each day and put it in a summary table. Thanks!